# No internet connection in PhoneGap app inside WP7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap app and testing on Windows Phone. I'm working with jQuery, including AJAX operation to grab data from websites. This works well on desktop browsers (including IE9) and Windows Phone 8 devices.

However, when I try to run my app in a WP7 emulator, AJAX requests keep resulting in an error: "No Internet session has been established". I checked if I could load an iframe, which didn't work either. Based on that, I guess my app doesn't have any internet connection. Even more confusing: `window.navigator.onLine` is true on startup.

The emulator itself does have internet connection; I can use the built-in browser without any problems.

What could be the reason for this issue; i.e. what further debugging steps can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the app's network connection by checking `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable` on startup, which returned false. After some digging in the dirt, I finally found the problem:

In my **`WMAppManifest`** file, all capabilities except `ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT` were disabled. Temporarily enabling all of them solved my issue (the relevant one for this issue is probably **`ID_CAP_NETWORKING`**).

***Why did it work on Windows Phone 8?***

My guess is that when running a WP7 app on a WP8 device, required capabilities are automatically detected, which would be strange, since the auto-detection of capabilities has been removed in the WP8 SDK. However, I couldn't find any documentation to clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a problem some of those, which i have faced, try something like:

First of i found out that when using jQuery + Windows Phone+ PhoneGap

Before calling AJAX function you must wait to event „deviceready” to fire and add 2 code rows:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    Examplerequest(); //Your request
}, false);
```

To access project files you need to make AJAX request
Function Examplerequest()
{

```
Var url = "www/templates/about/example.tpl";

$.ajax({
    url: url, //path to resource
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        //function on error
        alert(url + " Error: " + errorThrown);
    },
    dataType: options.externalTemplateDataType
}).done(function () { 
    //function when request is done
});
```

}

url – must NOT be relative! // in WP8 but in WP7 it must be relative ( or other way, don;t remember ).

Comment: I'm not using jQuery mobile, and the CORS line is already in my code. Also, relative paths are not a problem, since I'm grabbing data from another domain anyway. Waiting for the `deviceready` event might help, I'll check as soon as I get to do some coding...

Comment: Just tried it out: The `deviceread` event is not firing on WP7, though it does in WP8...

Comment: Another update: It fired after `$(document).ready`, but waiting for both didn't help either.

Comment: Ok, lets try another thing. Can you write a C# request? I suggest you creating a simple test project in C# to make a WebRequest and check that problem is not in Emulator/WebServise

Comment: And could you provide you'r request

Comment: Indeed, the app didn't have network connection due to missing capabilities (I still don't get it fully). See my answer for more details. Thx for your help!